# Sampling as adding random variables, especially binomial RVs

Tags: probability, sampling, random-variable, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Is sampling equivalent to adding random variables? I'm a bit confused because as we can see that the binomial distribution becomes more and more shaped like a normal distribution as $n$ increases. We're generally told it follows from the CLT, but why exactly is that? We're not talking about multiple samples, so we can't create a sampling distribution. Also generally when taking a sample with a large number of observations, it seems that we converge to a normal distribution anyways. So then, would this mean sampling is equivalent to summing up RVs from a sample?

Comment: (a) A binomial certainly is adding something; that something is Bernoulli successes. (b) However, especially when success probability $p$ is small, larger $n$ does not exactly cause convergence to symmetrical normal, sometimes larger $n$ along with small $p$ can lead to approximation by Poisson. // However, you say nothing about the point of your question as a practical matter of analyzing data. // If you have data, can you explain why they were collected and what you want to learn from them

Comment: But then what about if we reframe the question as Bernoulli successes? As in, how does a collection of 3 heads for example equate to adding?

Comment: The sum of $n=3$ independent Bernoulli random variables, each with the same success probability $p,$ is the $\mathsf{Binom}(n=3, p).$

Comment: But why might we be able to consider a collection of 3 samples from a Bernoulli as addition? As in what exactly is the intuition for that? Like would combining two samples from two different normal distributions be considered adding RVs?

Comment: The sum of $W \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n= 7, p = 1/2)$ and independent $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 3, p = 1/2)$ is $Y - W+X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10, p = 1/2).$ Altogether, $Y$ is the sum of ten Bernoulli's with success probability $1/2,$ as in tossing a fair coin ten times and counting the Heads. Maybe that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but why would "counting up the heads" be considered adding?

Comment: Why not? You toss the coin 7 times and get 3 heads, I toss it 3 times and get 1 head. So that's $3+1=4$ heads in ten tosses. // I see we've been busted for chatting in comments. Bed time here anyhow.

Comment: Yeah thanks :) I appreciate it. Do you happen to know of any other ways this applies? Where you may consider a collection of draws to be a sum?

Answer (score 2):

Sampling just means *selecting (and then observing) items from a larger population*; in statistics the sampling is usually randomised, and we are interested in the stochastic properties of random samples.  In any case, the notion of "sampling" is a general concept that goes far beyond consideration of the binomial distribution.  In some cases it will be valuable to sum the values in the sample, but obviously that operation is something that happens *after* you sample them.  So no --- "sampling" does not mean summing random variables from a sample.

Now, in the special case where we have an [exchangeable sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,X_2,X_3,...)$ (which we call a "superpopulation" since it is infinite) we get some results like what you are talking about.  Specifically, if we define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ to be the total number of positive values in a random sample of $n$ values, and we define $\theta = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n/n$ to be the long-run limiting proportion (our "probability parameter"), then we have the [Bernoulli model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution):

$$X_1,X_2,X_3,... \sim \text{IID Bern}(\theta).$$

This also implies that the total number of positive values follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

$$S_n \sim \text{Bin}(n, \theta).$$

You are also correct that the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) does indeed show that the binomial distribution converges to the normal distribution (in a suitably standardised sense) as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  This follows from the classical version of the theorem, from the fact that the values in the observable sequence are IID.

Answer (score 1):

Comment continued with examples:

$\mathsf{Binom}(n = 64, p = 1/2)$ [blue bars] compared with $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=32,\sigma=4)$ [red curve].

```
x = 0:64;  pdf = dbinom(x, 64, .5)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=3, col="blue")
 curve(dnorm(x, 32, 4), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

$\mathsf{Binom}(n = 128, p = 1/16)$ [blue bars] compared
with $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 8)$ [centers of open red dots].

```
x = 0:32; pdf = dbinom(x, 128, 1/16)
pdf.p = dpois(x, 8)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=2, col="blue")
 points(x, pdf.p, col="red")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

*Notes:* (1) The largest value of $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 128, p = 1/16)$ with positive probability is 128.
Technically, there is no largest value of
$\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 8)$ with positive
probability (the distribution has countably many positive values), but Poisson probabilities beyond about 128 are extremely small. (2) These two distributions are skewed slightly to the right (not symmetrical) so they are not
very well approximated by a normal distribution. As shown in R below,
if $Y\sim\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=8),$ then $P(Y\le 20) = 0.999906.$

```
qpois(.9999, 8)
[1] 20
ppois(20, 8)
[1] 0.999906
```